# Застраховаться от проблем с парсингом

Tags: python, парсер, веб-сайт

Пишу проект для курсовой работы, основанный на парсинге, за период разработки был случай, когда разработчики сайта меняли его и меняли его структуру, что соответственно всплыло на работу моего проекта. Теперь беспокоюсь, что в день сдачи курсовой может произойти такое же и хочу от этого застраховаться. Есть ли какие-нибудь варанты? Возможно, каким-то образом можно "запомнить" структуру сайта за конкретную дату? Какие идеи?

Comment: Можно через wget качнуть сайт( если там нет серверных скриптов). Можно с разработчиками договорится. Можно просить несколько сайтов и если один не захочет, будут другие. А можно написать код так, что бы прям на сдаче можно было подфиксить:).

Comment: Разве на сдаче не только презентация со скриншотами?

Comment: Сделайте свой сайт с блэкджеком и парсингом.

Comment: можно воспользоваться сервисами вроде [http://web.archive.org/](http://web.archive.org/) которые могут сохранять состояние сайта на определенную дату и ходить уже к нему